# Having Covariance / Contravariance problems with with this sample C# code

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I'm misunderstanding something obvious with inheritance. I've created a sample console app that has a few interfaces and classes which inherit from each other.

Using a factory, I'm trying to retrieve the appropriate service based on a given key. But the compiler is saying that it cannot add the concrete classes to the generic dictionary i'm asking it to.

Here's is what I'm trying to do:

*Given a factory, grab a service by keyname. Then execute the `Search` method, on this service.*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animalFactory = new AnimalFactory();

        // Search for some fishes.
        var fishService = animalFactory.GetAnimalService("fish");
        var fishes = fishService.SearchForAnimals(new FishSearchOptions {ScalesType = "shiny green"});

        // Search for meows.
        var catService = animalFactory.GetAnimalService("cat");
        var kittyCats = catService.SearchForAnimals(new MamalSearchOptions {HairColour = "golden"});
    }
}
```

So far so good? Take note, that each service can accept it's own specific search class, as an input parameter. eg. a `MamalService` can only accept a `MamalSearchOptions` class.

Here is the Factory...

```
public class AnimalFactory
{
    private IDictionary<string, IAnimalService<IAnimal, IAnimalSearchOptions>> _animals;

    public AnimalFactory()
    {
        _animals = new Dictionary<string, IAnimalService<IAnimal, IAnimalSearchOptions>>
            {
                {"Cat", new MamalService() },
                {"Dog", new MamalService() },
                {"GoldFish", new FishService() }
            };
    }

    public IAnimalService<IAnimal, IAnimalSearchOptions> GetAnimalService(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        return _animals[name];
    }
}
```

and here's the error message:

[image]

It doesn't like how i'm trying to insert the services into the (generic?) dictionary.

Now, what do the other classes and interfaces look like? Instead of spamming this thread, they can be [found in this gist, here](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/6025579). <-- Full 100% repo.

Can someone explain what I've done wrong and suggest what I need to do properly? I always thought that superclasses can always be inserted into a generic collection if they inherit from the generic collection's Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work if `IAnimalService` is **covariant** (e. g. declared as `IAnimalService<out TAnimal, out TSearchOptions>`).

Unfortunately, based on your factory interface, this doesn't seem like it will work. For example, you have:

```
public class MamalService : IAnimalService<MamalItem, MamalSearchOptions>
{
    public SearchResult<MamalItem> SearchForAnimals(MamalSearchOptions searchOptions)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class FishService : IAnimalService<Fish, FishSearchOptions>
{
    public SearchResult<Fish> SearchForAnimals(FishSearchOptions searchOptions)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If the compiler allowed your code, the following could happen:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IAnimalService<IAnimal, IAnimalSearchOptions>> {
    { "Dog", new MammalService() }
};

IAnimalService<IAnimal, IAnimalSearchOptions> service = dict["Dog"];

// this would be legal given the type of service, but would clearly not 
// be correct for MammalService:
IAnimal animal = service.SearchForAnimals(new FishSearchOptions());
```

In order to get this design to work, you might consider having `IAnimalService` take in just an `IAnimalSearchOptions` as its argument rather than a generic parameter. Then you could mark TAnimal as an out parameter and you'd be covariant. Of course, you'd also loose type-safety because your `MammalService` would have to cast the input `IAnimalSearchOptions` to `MammalSearchOptions`.

Another common solution is to have 2 versions of the interface, one generic and one not (like IEnumerable and IEnumerable) the non-generic version gives up some type-safety but is more useful in cases like the one you show above:

```
interface IAnimalService { IAnimal SearchForAnimals(IAnimalSearchOptions opts); }

interface IAnimalService<out TAnimal, in TOptions> : IAnimalService
    where TAnimal : IAnimal
    where TOptions : IAnimalSearchOptions {
    TAnimal SearchForAnimals(TOptions opts);
}

class MammalService : IAnimalService<Mammal, MammalSearchOptions>
{

    Mammal SearchForAnimals(MammalSearchOptions opts) { ... }

    IAnimal IAnimalService.SearchForAnimals(IAnimalSearchOptions opts)
    {
        return this.SearchForAnimals((MammalSearchOptions)opts);
    }
}
```

....

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IAnimalService> { "Dog", new MammalService() };
```